# How to use SSH in bash script to download files from bitbucket?

Tags: bash, git, curl, ssh

At my work, 
the current method of downloading custom git pre-commit hooks (from a bitbucket repo) uses `curl` in a bash script as shown :

where `$USERNAME`, `$PASSWORD` and `$build_support_url` are previously assigned.

```
...<some code>...    

# Download templates from http://swbuilds to home dir 
echo "Downloading pre-commit.pl hook"
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD --fail --show-error --silent --output ~/.git_template/hooks/pre-commit $build_support_url/pre-commit.pl
echo "Downloading prepare-commit-msg.py hook"
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD --fail --show-error --silent --output ~/.git_template/hooks/prepare-commit-msg $build_support_url/prepare-commit-msg.py
echo "Downloading commit-msg.py hook"
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD --fail --show-error --silent --output ~/.git_template/hooks/commit-msg $build_support_url/commit-msg.py

# Force the execute bit to be set 
chmod a+x  ~/.git_template/hooks/*

# Also download the customer list used by the pre-commit hook
echo "Downloading customer list"
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD --fail --show-error --silent --output ~/.git_template/customer_list.txt $build_support_url/customer_list.txt

# Configure Git templates
git config --global init.templatedir '~/.git_template'

...<some more code>...
```

This downloads the pre-commit hooks  from the link `$build_support_url/pre-commit.pl` and places them in the `~/.git_template` folder.
However, since this process is using `curl` with`HTTPS`, the script will require a password everytime it is run.

To avoid that hassle, I am told to edit the script so that, it uses `SSH` to download the files (which doesn't require a password).

Any suggestions on how to use `SSH` in this script to obtain those files?
Thanks.

PS: I have a crude idea of backend and API (and only know the basic HTTP requests like GET and POST. Hope that gives a little more context to the situation).

Comment: "the only thing related to ssh is" SSL != SSH.

Comment: right, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Does the bitbucket server have your public key?  i.e. Are you currently able to `git clone $build_support_url` or similar?

Comment: Yes, the bit-bucket server has my public key. And yes, I am currently able to git clone using ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was just to use the 'git archive' command instead of curl

Answer (score 1):

You can store your credentials in `~/.netrc` file so curl uses them as [explained here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html).